# Matlab Figure Display

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

So I have the following matlab code:

```
figure('Properties........');
mainFunctionClass.unzipper(handles);
```

I am trying to create a sort of a custom progress bar with the figure. But the problem here is, that the figure is being displayed AFTER the following function is complete. Is there a way to disply the figure first??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean

```
figure('Properties........');
drawnow
mainFunctionClass.unzipper(handles);
```

?

Comment: Yes! Wow that was an embarassingly simple solution...Thanks

Comment: @Adnan well, I know what a pain it can be to find simple things like these if you don't know them...Hurray for SO :)